# Waiting for finishing of all tasks with exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, wait

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) Task.WaitAll throughs the AggregateException as soon as an exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances.
I need wait for all the tasks are finished handling each thrown exception. So do I need make something like:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        break; //only if no exception is occured
    }
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    {
        //exceptions handling...
    }
}
```

or is some more rational way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs don't say that `WaitAll` returns as soon as one exception occurs. The opposite is true: it always waits for all tasks to complete.

> Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

This is already the behavior that you want.